# PHP imagecreatefromjpg() - quality default

Tags: php, image-processing

Sorry i'm using `imagecreatefromjpeg();`

What is the default image quality used to create?

Is there anyway to change that?

thanks

Comment: Quality is set upon *output*, not upon *input*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [`imagejpeg()`](http://www.php.net/imagejpeg) which sets the JPEG quality, and it defaults to 75. You can change the default quality passing an integer (from 0 to 100) as 3rd argument.